# Writing u as a linear combination of the vectors in S.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Write vector 
u = $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}2 \\10 \\1\end{array}\right]$$

as a linear combination of the vectors in S. Use elementary row operations on an augmented matrix to find the necessary coefficients.

S = {
$v1$$\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\\2\end{matrix}\right] , v2\left[\begin{matrix}4\\2\\1\end{matrix}\right],  
v2\left[\begin{matrix}5\\4\\1\end{matrix}\right]
$ }. If it is not possible, explain why?

---

This is what i have so far:

S = {
$v1$$\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\\2\end{matrix}\right] , v2\left[\begin{matrix}4\\2\\1\end{matrix}\right],  
v3\left[\begin{matrix}5\\4\\1\end{matrix}\right].
v4\left[\begin{matrix}2\\10\\1\end{matrix}\right]
$ } 

$c1$$\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\\2\end{matrix}\right] , c2\left[\begin{matrix}4\\2\\1\end{matrix}\right],  
c3\left[\begin{matrix}5\\4\\1\end{matrix}\right].
c4\left[\begin{matrix}2\\10\\1\end{matrix}\right]
=\left[\begin{matrix}0\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right]$

$c1$$\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\\2\end{matrix}\right] , c2\left[\begin{matrix}4\\2\\1\end{matrix}\right],  
c3\left[\begin{matrix}5\\4\\1\end{matrix}\right].
c4\left[\begin{matrix}2\\10\\1\end{matrix}\right]$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 5 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 4 & 10\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Now i don't know how to do this. Help will greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: “It's elementary, Watson.”  I'ld suggest strongly to ask some colleagues or to heavily study your textbook.

Answer (score 2):

$a\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\\2\end{matrix}\right] + b\left[\begin{matrix}4\\2\\1\end{matrix}\right]+  
c\left[\begin{matrix}5\\4\\1\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}2\\10\\1\end{matrix}\right]$.

Putting this into matrix form gives:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&4&5&2\\2&2&4&10\\2&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&4&5&2\\1&1&2&5\\2&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&4&5&2\\0&3&3&-3\\0&7&9&3\end{bmatrix}\\\to\begin{bmatrix}1&4&5&2\\0&1&1&-1\\
0&7&9&3\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&6\\0&1&1&-1\\0&0&1&5\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&1&0&-6\\0&0&1&5\end{bmatrix}$.

So, $a=1,b=-6,c=5.$

Plug the values back in to check if this is indeed correct:

$1\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\\2\end{matrix}\right]  -6\left[\begin{matrix}4\\2\\1\end{matrix}\right]+  
5\left[\begin{matrix}5\\4\\1\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}2\\10\\1\end{matrix}\right]$$\implies$$\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\\2\end{matrix}\right] + \left[\begin{matrix}-24\\-12\\-6\end{matrix}\right]+  
\left[\begin{matrix}25\\20\\5\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}2\\10\\1\end{matrix}\right]$.

So, it must be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve the system

> $$ c_1\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\\2\end{matrix}\right] + c2\left[\begin{matrix}4\\2\\1\end{matrix}\right]+  
> c3\left[\begin{matrix}5\\4\\1\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}2\\10\\1\end{matrix}\right] .$$

Answer (score 1):

You're heading in the right direction, you've found the [augmented matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix):
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 4 & 5 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 4 & 10\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}\right].
$$
The solutions $(x,y,z)$ to this [system of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) are precisely the values for which $$x\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}5 \\ 4 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 10\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

So, we solve the above system of linear equations using elementary row operations on the augmented matrix, to reduce it to [row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).  Then, if the system of equations turns out to be consistent (i.e., if there is a solution), we use back substitution to find all the solutions $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: In what situation would it be impossible for the vectors to be a combination of the other vector?